# .NET MAUI Not redirecting back after authentication

Tags: c#, android, .net, maui

I have been following [this Microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/mobile-apps/azure-mobile-apps/quickstarts/maui/authentication) on how to setup MAUI with MSAL authentication but I am having issues where it does not redirect to my app after I sign in my outlook account.

I added these to an existing MAUI app without going through a sample app so maybe there is something missing from my app?

The authentication popup opens properly and it returns to my code if I close the authentication popup but if I click "continue" in the Microsoft login popup, it acts like it wants to load a page and then just stops and I am left with the same page.

I did add the `MsalActivity.cs` to Platforms/Android, I added the required line to the manifest, added the `platform.OnActivityResult` to the MauiProgram.cs file... I also did enable the `msal{client-id}` and "native client" redirect URI. Not sure what to check next! The actual authentication seems to work, it just doesn't go back to my app unless I cancel the authentication.

I am also requesting the authentication randomly on a button click like so:

```cs
private async void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var token = await GetAuthenticationToken();
}
```

I assumed that wouldn't be an issue...
Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up finding the issue. When following the tutorial this piece of code didn't compile because it wasn't finding the `Intent.ActionView` and the 2 others :

```cs
[Activity(Exported = true)]
[IntentFilter([Intent.ActionView],
    Categories = [Intent.CategoryBrowsable, Intent.CategoryDefault],
    DataHost = "auth",
    DataScheme = "msalb78...57")]
public class MsalActivity : BrowserTabActivity
{
}
```

I had wrongly replaced them by just wrapping them in strings like `"Intent.ActionView"`. I switched it all to this and now it works :

```cs
[Activity(Exported = true)]
[IntentFilter(["android.intent.action.VIEW"],
    Categories = ["android.intent.category.BROWSABLE", "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"],
    DataHost = "auth",
    DataScheme = "msalb78...57")]
public class MsalActivity : BrowserTabActivity
{
}
```

Still not sure why I don't have the "Intent.ActionView"

Comment: I am having the same issue. Not able to solve with the above solution